# Can someone explain where this comes from for the cauchy-euler equation in the case of double roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am not sure how the following was derived in my textbook given by [image]

I understand that the solution we are seeking is $y = x^r$ and the fact that we obtained the first solution as $y = c_1 x^{r_1}$ and that we are looking for a 2nd solution, by taking the derivative with respect to $r$. However, it is a bit puzzling as to how equation (3.8) was arrived at, and in particular how $$L[\frac{\partial}{\partial r} x^r] = L[x^r\log{x}]$$

Would someone mind explaining please? Explanations are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

\begin{equation}
x^r=\left(e^{\ln x}\right)^r=e^{r\ln x}
\end{equation}

Therefore

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}x^r=(\ln x) e^{r\ln x}=x^r\ln x
\end{equation}